# Не отправляются сообщения от клиента к серверу через socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, chat

Пишу пробный чат на python 3. Есть два файла - клиент и сервер. Используется библиотеки "socket" и "threading". По задумке клиентская часть должна отправлять сообщение серверной, вот часть кода, который это должен делать:

```py
key = 8194 ###

shutdown = False
join = False

def receving (name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                #print(data.decode("utf-8"))

                # Begin
                decrypt = ""; k = False
                for i in data.decode("utf-8"):
                    if i == ":":
                        k = True
                        decrypt += i
                    elif k == False or i == " ":
                        decrypt += i
                    else:
                        decrypt += chr(ord(i)^key)
                print(decrypt)
                # End

                sleep(0.2)
        except:
            pass
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 0

server = ("***.***.***.***",9090)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.setblocking(0)

alias = logins

rT = threading.Thread(target = receving, args = ("RecvThread",s))
rT.start()

while shutdown == False:
    if join == False:
        s.sendto(("["+alias + "] => присоеденился к чату. ").encode("utf-8"),server)
        join = True
    else:
        try:
            message = input()

            # Begin
            crypt = ""
            for i in message:
                crypt += chr(ord(i)^key)
            message = crypt
            # End

            if message != "":
                s.sendto(("["+alias + "] :: "+message).encode("utf-8"),server)

            sleep(0.2)
        except:
            s.sendto(("["+alias + "] <= покинул чат. ").encode("utf-8"),server)
            shutdown = True

rT.join()
s.close() ###
```

Серверная часть которая должна принимать эти сообщения:

```py
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 9090

clients = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))

quit = False
print("[ MFCS v0.1.1 ] - Сервер запущен! ")

while not quit:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)

        itsatime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S", time.localtime())

        print("["+addr[0]+"]=["+str(addr[1])+"]=["+itsatime+"]/",end="")
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))

        for client in clients:
            if addr != client:
                s.sendto(data,client)
    except: 
        print("\n[ MFCS v0.1.1 ] - Сервер остановлен из-за ошибки! ]")
        quit = True

s.close()
```

Но когда запускаешь серверную и клиентские части, то при написании чего-либо в поле ввода это сообщение не отправляется на сервер и, соответственно, на второй клиент.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в `s.bind((host,port))` на месте host прописать `"0.0.0.0"`. Если я не ошибаюсь, там указывается не адрес машины, на которой запускается сокет, а маска.

Еще заметил, что у вас клиент делает `bind`. Такого быть не должно. Вот рабочий пример [клиент-сервера udp](http://snakeproject.ru/rubric/article.php?art=python_udp_network_server_client).

Comment: Выдает, что неверный синтаксис.

Comment: @andr0meda , `s.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))` на эту строку ругается?

Comment: Уже не ругается, но сообщения все-равно не отправляет.

Comment: @andr0meda еще заметил, что у вас клиент делает bind. Такого быть не должно. Вот рабочий пример клиент-сервера [udp](http://snakeproject.ru/rubric/article.php?art=python_udp_network_server_client)